# "The update is already installed on this system" message when trying to apply hotfixes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, patch-management, service-pack, windows

I was trying to install ([KB2460011](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2460011) and [KB2516475](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2516475)) to windows Server 2008R2 SP1 Standard after suggested as a fix for SQL Server crashing issue and it gives me update is already installed message/error but I don’t see the hotfixes applied when I check in control panel and using **`get-hotfix`** after reboot. Not sure what is happening but my hunch is they might already be included with service pack. How do I make sure they are really applied, if not how can I apply them.(I am a DBA not a sysadmin ;)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the KB articles for the updates indicating which files and which versions are being replaced. In addition, you can try to extract the files from the fix archive and compare it to the ones on the system.